# How to call function in Vue Component without lambda expression

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I use Vue Js 2.6, and have made this component:

```
Vue.component('confirmmodal', {
template: '',
data: function () {
    return {
        showModal: false,
        title: '',
        text: '',
        confirmMethod: null,
        dismissMethod: null,
        compiledTemplate: null
    };
},
methods: {
    initTemplate: function (result) {
        this.compiledTemplate = Vue.compile(result); //called from created
        return;
    },
    show: function (t) {
        this.showModal = true;
    },
    ok: function () {
        this.showModal = false;
        if (this.confirmMethod) {
            this.confirmMethod();
        }
    },
    cancel: function () {
        this.showModal = false;
        if (this.dismissMethod) {
            this.dismissMethod();
        }
    }
},
render: function (createElement) {
    if (this.compiledTemplate) {
        return this.compiledTemplate.render.call(this, createElement);
    }
},
created: function () {
    site.apiGetHtml("/home/ConfirmModal/", null, this.initTemplate, null, null);
    modalhandle.$on('toggleConfirm', content => {
        this.title = content.title;
        this.text = content.text.replace('§', '<br />');
        this.confirmMethod = content.confirm;
        this.dismissMethod = content.dismiss;
        //this.$root.$options.components.confirmmodal.options.methods.show(content);
        this.show();
    });
}
});
```

Maybee its a bad way to implement it, but in my ASP.NET projects, I have made som partial views, loaded in the site.apiGetHtml function, compiled into the component, when it is created. And it works fine.

The component works fine in Chrome and other browsers supporting ES6. But our customer requires supporting IE11 - and there the problem comes, as IE11 not supports lambda-expression:

```
     content => {
        this.title = content.title;
        this.text = content.text.replace('§', '<br />');
        this.confirmMethod = content.confirm;
        this.dismissMethod = content.dismiss;
        this.show();
     }
```

When I convert the lambda-expression into a function, the 'this' variable can not find the show-function in the component (even not in Chrome).
As you can see, I have tried to call the show function - through the this.$root.components scope, but it looks like I dont get the component initialized. Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try having assigning this to a variable so that it's context is not lost in function:

```
let self = this;            
function(content) {
        self.title = content.title;
        self.text = content.text.replace('§', '<br />');
        self.confirmMethod = content.confirm;
        self.dismissMethod = content.dismiss;
        self.show();
     }
```

Comment: thanks a lot - saved me from rewriting several components.